# Sum of SubQuery Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to get the Sum of SubQuery Column. Here is what I am using, but it is giving error,

```
SELECT SUM (SELECT Col1 From Table1) FROM Table 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are not selecting anything from Table2, you can just do:

```
select sum(Col1) 
from Table1
```

Otherwise, you can do it like this:

```
select (
        select sum(Col1)
        from Table1
        ) as SumTable1Col1,
    Table2.SomeOtherCol
from Table2
```

Comment: This is just an example, my query is very comples

Comment: @user960567: See my second example.